# Is there a simple way to randomly pick from a list with the exception of one element?

Tags: python, list, random

If I wanted to pick randomly from a list like this, and I got b...

```
list=[a,b,c,d]
```

Is there a simple way to pick another element from the list, without picking b again, without altering the list in anyway?

Comment: There are several ways which all seem straighforward. Did you try any of them? For example: (1) Loop until the randomly chosen element isn't b; (2) Create a copy of the list without b from which you choose

Comment: Well I'm trying to learn about efficiency. I was just wondering if there was a one line, syntax way to doing it, but if there's not, I'll just settle for loops.

Comment: Do you want to pick 2 or more distinct items from your list? There is a `random.sample` function for that. Anyway, your question is unclear...

Comment: And if only one item is needed, there is also [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) (but it doesn't address the 'without picking b again' part of the problem)

Comment: Best idea might be to use a copy of this list and `shuffle` it. Then `pop` one element after another.

Comment: if the list is large; rejection sampling is often the most efficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population
> sequence or set. Used for random sampling ***without replacement***.

```
>>> import random
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> random.sample(l, 3) # Pick 3 random elements without replacement from l
['c', 'd', 'a']
```

Comment: Probably better to say ```random.sample(l, len(l)-1)``` for a more general case. Didn't know about ```random.sample()``` though - very cool trick.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the answer by Shash Sinha is certainly what you are looking for, you can play around with recursion a bit as well (this does alter the original list, so its not ideal):

```
import random

choices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def chooseRandom():
    
    if len(choices) > 0:

        choice = choices.pop(random.randint(0, len(choices)-1))

        print (f'Chosen Character: {choice}')
        print (f'Remaining Choices: {choices}')

        chooseRandom()
        
chooseRandom()
```

Which would output something similar to the following (depending on what is randomly chosen):

```
Chosen Character: c
Remaining Choices: ['a', 'b', 'd']
Chosen Character: a
Remaining Choices: ['b', 'd']
Chosen Character: b
Remaining Choices: ['d']
Chosen Character: d
Remaining Choices: []
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
import random

list = ['a', 'b' , 'c', 'd']
list2 = copy.deepcopy(list)
random.shuffle(list2)
for i in list2:
   # i is now a random item from original list
   do_something(i)
```

You can also just pop() off list2 when you need a random item